# Properties file could not be found by getResourceAsStream(). Check the CLASSPATH or class loader

Tags: java, maven, classpath, getresource

This is from an open source project where there is nearly no support. Compilation of the project went well. But I cannot test or install because of a particular property file cannot be found. I have search up and down the internet and not able to find any solutions. The organization of the director is a little bit unconventional.

some directories.
core/src/main/java/org/mskcc/cbio/portal/util/Config.java.

```
String props = "portal.properties";
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(props);
...
```

more directoires.
src/main/resources/portal.properties.

This last src directory has only one subdirectory main,
and the main directory has only one resources subdirectory.
The file that could not be found is located here.

I am using java 1.7.  Maven 3.0.5
The command I used is mvn install

I must be missing one simple configuration somewhere.

There got to be some who can resolve this easily.

Comment: *"This is from an open source project.."*  There are a few of them.  Care to narrow it down with a link, to save us going "up and down the internet" looking for it?

Comment: How is the organization "unconventional"? Looks like a normal Maven project to me with the limited information provided, and with a successful Maven build, "portal.properties" will be where it should be. Perhaps you should check the final jar for it.

Answer (score 1):

*src/main/resources* is, by default, the path of Aplication/Library resources in Maven. But, you can optionally force this in the pom.xml.

1) Add in the pom.xml

```
<resource>
   <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
   <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

2) run maven -> *mvn clean install*

3) Search for *portal.properties* at the build generated at "target" folder. Assert that *portal.properties* is in the root of the artifact classpath  (root of .jar, .ear or /classes in .war).